# Ionic 2 Add radio buttons to alert controller

Tags: ionic2, radio-button

How to add radio buttons as inputs buttons in an alert controller in ionic 2?
It works with check boxes, but i want to add radio button group with radio buttons to select only one option.

```
  advanceSearch(): void{
   let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'something',
    message: 'Select option ',
    inputs : [
     {
       type:'checkbox',
       label:'something1'
     },
     {
       type:'checkbox',
       label:'something2'
      }

    ],
    buttons : [
     {
       text: "Cancel",
       handler: data => {
         console.log("cancel clicked");
       }
     },
     {
       text: "Search",
       handler: data => {
         console.log("search clicked");
       }
     }
    ]
    });
    prompt.present();
}
```

`

I want to change these check boxes to radio boxes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this.

```
advanceSearch(): void
{
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'something',
    message: 'Select option ',
    inputs : [
    {
        type:'radio',
        label:'something1',
        value:'something1'
    },
    {
        type:'radio',
        label:'something2',
        value:'something2'
    }],
    buttons : [
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        handler: data => {
        console.log("cancel clicked");
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Search",
        handler: data => {
        console.log("search clicked");
        }
    }]});
    prompt.present();
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Dinuka

Comment: is it  possible to set Boolean  to value of a button

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that cuttenly `AlertController.create` method returns `Promise<HTMLIonAlertElement>` so you have to create it using `async / await`:

```js
async advanceSearch(): void
{
  let prompt = await this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'something',
    message: 'Select option ',
    inputs : [
    {
        type:'radio',
        label:'something1',
        value:'something1'
    },
    {
        type:'radio',
        label:'something2',
        value:'something2'
    }],
    buttons : [
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        handler: data => {
        console.log("cancel clicked");
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Search",
        handler: data => {
        console.log("search clicked");
        }
    }]});

   await prompt.present();
}
```